# what are these gray lines inside the bars of my ggplot bargraph?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I wanted to create a graph to show which continent has the highest co2 emissions total per capita over the years,
so I coded this:

```
barchart <- ggplot(data = worldContinents, 
                   aes(x = Continent, 
                   y = `Per.Capita`, 
                   colour = Continent)) 
         + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
barchart
```

This is my dataframe:

[image: dataframe]

`Geometry` is just for some geographical mapping later.

I checked `which(is.na(worldContinents$Per.Capita))` to see whether there were `NA` values but it returned nothing
What's causing these gray lines?
How do I get rid of them?

These are the gray lines inside the bar graph
[image: gray lines inside the bars]

Thank you

Comment: Please share your data using `dput(df)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple of issues here. First of all, I'm guessing you want the `fill` to be mapped to the continent, not `color`, which only controls the color of the bars' outlines.

Secondly, there are multiple values for each continent in your data, so they are simply stacking on top of each other. This is the reason for the lines in your bars, and is probably not what you want. If you want the *average* value per capita in each continent, you either need to summarise your data beforehand or use `stat_summary` like this:

```r
barchart <- ggplot(data = worldContinents, 
                   aes(x = Continent, 
                       y = `Per.Capita`, 
                       fill = Continent))  +
            stat_summary(geom = "col", fun = mean, width = 0.7,
                         col = "gray50") +
            theme_light(base_size = 20) +
            scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Spectral")
barchart
```

[image]

---

**Data used**

Obviously, we don't have your data, so I used a modified version of the `gapminder` data set to match your own data structure

```r
worldContinents <- gapminder::gapminder
worldContinents$Per.Capita <- worldContinents$gdpPercap
worldContinents$Continent <- worldContinents$continent
worldContinents <- worldContinents[worldContinents$year == 2007,]
```